# Laravel nginx default file

Tags: laravel, nginx

I try to configure my laravel installation on a digital ocean instance with nginx running.

The default config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/mfserver/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name IPADDRESS;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args&args =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/mfserver/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args&args =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when I call a route like /v1/aeds I get an error 404. Is the config not setup properly?

The route file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'SERVERIP', 'namespace' => 'API'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'v1'], function() {
        // AED ROUTES
        Route::get('/aeds', 'AED\APIAEDController@index');
        Route::post('/aeds', 'AED\APIAEDController@store');
        Route::get('/aeds/{aeds}', 'AED\APIAEDController@show');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args&args =404;
}
```

With this:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
error_page 404 /index.php;
```

Comment: Nice.. worked! Where is the difference if I may ask?

Comment: @sesc360 - I believe yours might have worked if you added the question mark between php and $is_args, but I'm not sure. Mind marking the answer as accepted for others who have the same issue?

Comment: will do.. in 4 mins :) Not allowed to do yet ;)